How do I fix this baking issue that occurs when I unwrap an object with an array of tiles/bricks?
Please help!
I've been having some issues with baking objects that have a lot of polygons as a whole, and I don't know how to fix it. I'm really bad at explaining things so bear with me! First, I'll go over how I made this model and images of the expected result vs the actual result.
Here's how I created the model:
Modeling

Add square object and make rectangle
Create an Array and then add another modifier to randomize bricks
(can't remember the name)
Add Bevel, then join as one object

Texturing
For the texturing, I procedurally made the texture through gradient nodes and added the Ambient Occlusion with the Render Engine: Eevee.
Please Note: I changed the engine near the end to Cycles as it keeps the Ambient Occlusion effect (this process has not affected other 3D Models).
Lastly, I unwrapped the model (see image) and tried to render a Diffuse Map. Some people in my circle who do 3D Modeling, but not in Blender, thought the problem was the geometry having extra vertices, etc.. However, I do not have any issues with my geometry. I think it has to do with the number of bricks in this model or the rendering settings, but I am open to any other solutions.
If the problem is because of how many objects I joined, how would you go about baking these maps?
I am grateful for any suggestions or possible solutions; thank you in advance!
Image Examples
Expected Result:

Actual Result:

UV Map:

